# JavaScript function which can validate multiple forms on a webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html

Apologies if this is a straightforward question, as I am still very new to JavaScript. I have a script that validates user inputs by checking if the text-field is empty. If it is not empty, then a confirmation window prompts the user to make sure they want to continue before the form is submitted and the information uploaded.

I would like to know how I can use the code below or similar code to validate multiple forms on the same page, as currently I can only get it to work with one single form? I have tried various solutions, non of which have yet been successful. I have even tried copy/pasting the entire script and changing the relevant elements inside it.

I've stripped my alterations to the code back to where it actually works correctly. Like I said, once I try to re-use it to validate multiple forms, the code stops working correctly.

```js
// Set up event handlers in JavaScript
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', validationCheck);
document.getElementById('updateEventTitle').addEventListener('keyup', validationCheck);
// Get your DOM references just once, not every time the function runs
let eventTitle = document.getElementById('updateEventTitle');
let btnUpdate = document.getElementById('updateBtn');
function validationCheck(event) {
  if (eventTitle.value === '') {
    btnUpdate.disabled = true;
  } else {
    btnUpdate.disabled = false;
    //Confirmation window
    if (event.type === 'submit') {
      //Confirmation window
      var r = confirm('Do you want to update this item?');
      if (r == true) {
        window.location.href = 'server.php';
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form action='editevent.php?updaterow=$iddata' method='POST' id='updateEventTitle'>
  <input type='text' id='updateEventTitle' name='myUpdateEventTitle' size='30' maxlength='40' placeholder='$row[eventName]' required>
  <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='updateEventTitle' value='Update' id='updateBtn' disabled>
</form>
<form action='editevent.php?updaterow=$iddata' method='POST' id='updateEventDate'>
  <input type='text' id='updateEventDate' name='myUpdateEventDate' size='15' maxlength='10' placeholder=$eventDate required/>
  <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='updateEventDate' value='Update' id='updateBtn' disabled>
</form>
<form action='editevent.php?updaterow=$iddata' method='POST' id='updateEventTime'>
  <input type='text' id='updateEventTime' name='myUpdateEventTime' size='15' maxlength='5' placeholder=$eventTime required/>
  <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='updateEventTime' value='Update' id='updateBtn' disabled>
</form>
```

I would like a script that is able to validate any HTML `form` on the page, not just the first one.

Many thanks.

Comment: Why not having just one form for all 3, as the `action` is always the same?

Comment: The feature is for a page which allows users to update information regarding upcoming events. I wasn't sure if a single form for all updatable content was suitable as the user would commonly only be updating one thing at a time. It made sense for me to therefor to split the content into separate forms but perhaps this is the wrong/overly complex approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We simply can took all the forms, loop through, get inputs and buttons we need for every form and set up listeners for every form, for every element.

Below is a code snippet explaining how it can be done.

```js
// getting all forms
const elForms = [...document.querySelectorAll('form')];

// looping an array
elForms.map(elForm => {
  // Get your DOM references just once, not every time the function runs
  const elInput  = elForm.querySelector(`input[type='text']`);
  const elButton = elForm.querySelector(`input[type='submit']`);

  // Set up event handlers in JavaScript
  elForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => validationCheck(event, elInput, elButton)); // passing parameters
  elInput.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => validationCheck(event, elInput, elButton)); // passing parameters
});

function validationCheck(event, elInput, elButton) {
    if(elInput.value==='') { 
        elButton.disabled = true; 
    } else { 
        elButton.disabled = false;

        //Confirmation window
        if(event.type === 'submit'){
            //Confirmation window
            var r =confirm('Do you want to update this item?');
            if (r==true)    {
                window.location.href = 'server.php';
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form action='editevent.php?updaterow=$iddata' method='POST' id='updateEventTitle'>
     <input type='text' id='updateEventTitle' name='myUpdateEventTitle' size='30' maxlength='40' placeholder='$row[eventName]' required>
     <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='updateEventTitle' value='Update' id='updateBtn' disabled> 
</form>

<form action='editevent.php?updaterow=$iddata' method='POST' id='updateEventDate'>
     <input type='text' id='updateEventDate' name='myUpdateEventDate' size='15' maxlength='10' placeholder=$eventDate required/> 
     <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='updateEventDate' value='Update' id='updateBtn' disabled> 
</form>

<form action='editevent.php?updaterow=$iddata' method='POST' id='updateEventTime'>
     <input type='text' id='updateEventTime' name='myUpdateEventTime' size='15' maxlength='5' placeholder=$eventTime required/> 
     <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='updateEventTime' value='Update' id='updateBtn' disabled> 
</form>
```

**After answer**

There are duplicating `id` in your example

```
<form action='editevent.php?updaterow=$iddata' method='POST' id='updateEventTitle'>
  <input type='text' id='updateEventTitle'
```

This is not valid and can cause problems in future. `id` should be unique.